# Modifying a .class file within a Minecraft mod

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, compilation, minecraft

I've used JD-Gui to decompile the `.class` files thanks to a suggestion I found on an unrelated question and I used Eclipse to edit the `.java` code.

The issue comes when I recompile it into a `.class` file using the build function of Eclipse. Instead of creating a `.class` with all the code of the `.java` within it, it creates a `.class` that has replaced every function with an output stating what the error is. I thought when you told the compiler to compile with the errors it would use the code as is instead of replacing the code with the errors.

All I want to do is modify the `.class` file and I can't seem to find a solution to my issue. Is there any way to actually compile the code as is instead of being replaced with the error that the code generates?

Comment: what error are you talking about? if you really want to be sure to be able to do it right, you'll need to alter the source code, not decompiled class files, since there's no way to guarantee the decompiled version is in fact the code that was compiled originally

Comment: in the .java file "public void func_78088_a" will contain code pertaining to what the function would do, like declaring where the body pieces of the mob belong. However, in the compiled .class file, the function only contains a singular line of code "throw error " and then a description of the error in quotes.

Comment: doesn't really sound like a compiled class to me

Comment: Eclipse does not replace parts in a `.class` file but recreates the `.class` file completely. The option to compile even if there are errors means to skip parts containing errors but compile everything else.

Comment: is there any way to get it to compile the errors or am I looking at an impossible problem? all of the issues are with the fact that the IDE doesn't know exactly the files being called by the one I'm attempting to modify and the IDE won't compile without knowing the source of every call made by the file.

Comment: Azarius ... as recommended earlier, get the original project with source code

Comment: the source code seems to be available, but, it has gradle and I am unsure how to access that.

Comment: That's a different question, but if you need help with it feel free to ask on it's own question. If the source is available, most repositories have a readme on how to build.

Vogella usually has excellent tutorials, and appears to cover it. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Decompiling and modifying .class files manually is NOT recommended for Minecraft modding!

Your options in preference order:

1. Find the source of the mod and fork it.
2. Request the mod author add an API for what you want to change.
3. Patch the mods code at runtime.
4. Decompile the mod (possibly breaking it's license) using [BON2](https://github.com/tterrag1098/BON2/releases) or MCP/ForgeGradle to get sources that resemble the original deobfuscated source.

That said, if you are set on doing 4, you are going to need to find all the libraries it uses to compile against again.

> it creates a .class that has replaced every function with an output
>   stating what the error is. I thought when you told the compiler to
>   compile with the errors it would use the code as is instead of
>   replacing the code with the errors.

This is the expected behavior. Compile with errors is largely intended for use with hotswappable code, so you can prototype rapidly without worrying about the source being 100% compileable, it is impossible for it to link to dependencies it doesn't have.

> Is there any way to actually compile the code as is instead of being
>   replaced with the error that to code generates?

Modify the bytecode directly, or follow one of the options above.

Comment: Note: option 3 (modifying the bytecode at runtime) is *highly* discouraged. It's called a "coremod" and it is very easy to royally screw up when writing a coremod, and the issues you create may not even be obvious and any crashes will not appear to reference your classes.